# Unexpected result in integral calculation

Tags: python, sympy

Basically not getting the expected result,

I am getting the following

```
exp(-infinity*sign(a**2)))
```

I tried the following

```py
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
a = sp.Symbol('a')
def f(x,a):
    return (a-x)**2/(a**2)
sp.exp(-1*sp.integrate(f(x,a),(x,0,oo)))
```

Result should be

```
(3a**2 - 3*a + 1)/(3a**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you expect a finite result here:

```
In [20]: Integral((a-x)**2, (x, 0 ,oo))                                                                                           
Out[20]: 
∞            
⌠            
⎮        2   
⎮ (a - x)  dx
⌡            
0            

In [21]: Integral((a-x)**2, (x, 0 ,oo)).doit()                                                                                    
Out[21]: ∞
```